# Update Single Row Based on URI Android Content Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am using Content  Provider for database operations ,have insert the record in database successfully using following code

```
     ContentValues messageContentValues = new ContentValues ( );

        // time stamp of message
        messageContentValues.put (Conversation.COLUMN_TIME_STAMP, HeyUtil.getCurrentTime ( ));
        // date stamp of message
        messageContentValues.put (Conversation.COLUMN_DATE_STAMP, HeyUtil.getCurrentDate ( ));


        messageContentValues.put (Conversation.COLUMN_MEDIA_NAME, fileName);

            // Content providers Entry
        Uri uri = getContentResolver ( ).insert (
                MyContentProviders.CONVERSATION_CONTENT_URI, messageContentValues);
```

Successful insertion give me the `URI`

**Now my question is can i use this URI  to update the record ?**

example

```
 // creat a content value for column you want to update
                        ContentValues mContentValues = new ContentValues ();
                        mContentValues.put (Conversation.COLUMN_MEDIA_NAME, "abde");


   // uri= record insertion URI
            getContentResolver ().update (uri,mContentValues,null,null);
```

Comment: Did you write the `ContentProvider`? Does it return a valid `Uri` from `insert()`? Is its `update()` method written to handle a `Uri` like that?

Comment: @MikeM.  yes all are there

Comment: Well, then, yeah, sure. As long as the `Uri` is pointing to a unique record, and your `update()` method knows how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is can i use this URI to update the record ?

As Mike M. indicates, that is up to you. If you wrote the `ContentProvider`, you can implement the `update()` method however you want. If you want to pull an ID value off of the `Uri` and use that to update a single entry, you are welcome to do so.